# How to parse all given arguments in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to create a loop function that looks like this:

```
function Loop { foreach ($File in Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -exp Name) { # Some command } }
```

It works perfectly fine for simple one-word commands, but it doesn't work for anything else. Of course, I need a way to parse all given arguments, but I don't know how. All documentations that I've been able to understand (I just started working with PowerShell about a week ago) don't seem to have an answer to this.

It would be great if someone could give me a solution to this problem.

Comment: `# Some command` is the part where you need help ? basically you want to pass an expression that does something inside the loop as argument to your function ?

Comment: Where do "all given arguments" come from?

Comment: Please, share an example of what you're looking to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Like issuing several commands inside the loop?

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell
function script:Loop {
    foreach ($File in Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) {
        ##Some command 
        ##another command
        ## a test
        Write-Output -InputObject ('The current item is named {0}.' -f $file)
    }
}

Loop
```

#### output

```
PS C:\Powershell\Scripts> . "c:\Powershell\Scripts\forloop.ps1"
The current item is named dchero.ps1.
The current item is named findinstaller.ps1.
The current item is named Untitled11.ps1.
The current item is named Untitled5.ps1.
The current item is named Untitled8.ps1.
```

However you don't really need to do the `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` because `Get-ChildItem` returns multiple properties for the objects it finds. You can see all of them by piping into `Get-Member`

```
PS C:\Powershell\Scripts> Get-ChildItem | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition
----                      ----------     ----------
Target                    AliasProperty  Target = LinkTarget
LinkType                  CodeProperty   System.String LinkType{get=GetLinkType;}
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}
ModeWithoutHardLink       CodeProperty   System.String ModeWithoutHardLink{get=ModeWithoutHardLink;}
AppendText                Method         System.IO.StreamWriter AppendText()
CopyTo                    Method         System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(string destFileName), System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(string destFileName, bool overwrite)
Create                    Method         System.IO.FileStream Create()
CreateAsSymbolicLink      Method         void CreateAsSymbolicLink(string pathToTarget)
CreateText                Method         System.IO.StreamWriter CreateText()
Decrypt                   Method         void Decrypt()
Delete                    Method         void Delete()
Encrypt                   Method         void Encrypt()
Equals                    Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method         int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method         System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetObjectData             Method         void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context), void ISerializab… 
GetType                   Method         type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method         System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
MoveTo                    Method         void MoveTo(string destFileName), void MoveTo(string destFileName, bool overwrite)
Open                      Method         System.IO.FileStream Open(System.IO.FileMode mode), System.IO.FileStream Open(System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access), System.IO.F… 
OpenRead                  Method         System.IO.FileStream OpenRead()
OpenText                  Method         System.IO.StreamReader OpenText()
OpenWrite                 Method         System.IO.FileStream OpenWrite()
Refresh                   Method         void Refresh()
Replace                   Method         System.IO.FileInfo Replace(string destinationFileName, string destinationBackupFileName), System.IO.FileInfo Replace(string destinationFileName,… 
ResolveLinkTarget         Method         System.IO.FileSystemInfo ResolveLinkTarget(bool returnFinalTarget)
ToString                  Method         string ToString()
PSChildName               NoteProperty   string PSChildName=dchero.ps1
PSDrive                   NoteProperty   PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C
PSIsContainer             NoteProperty   bool PSIsContainer=False
PSParentPath              NoteProperty   string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Powershell\Scripts
PSPath                    NoteProperty   string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Powershell\Scripts\dchero.ps1
PSProvider                NoteProperty   ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
Attributes                Property       System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}
CreationTime              Property       datetime CreationTime {get;set;}
CreationTimeUtc           Property       datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}
Directory                 Property       System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory {get;}
DirectoryName             Property       string DirectoryName {get;}
Exists                    Property       bool Exists {get;}
Extension                 Property       string Extension {get;}
FullName                  Property       string FullName {get;}
IsReadOnly                Property       bool IsReadOnly {get;set;}
LastAccessTime            Property       datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}
LastAccessTimeUtc         Property       datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}
LastWriteTime             Property       datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}
LastWriteTimeUtc          Property       datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}
Length                    Property       long Length {get;}
LinkTarget                Property       string LinkTarget {get;}
Name                      Property       string Name {get;}
BaseName                  ScriptProperty System.Object BaseName {get=if ($this.Extension.Length -gt 0){$this.Name.Remove($this.Name.Length - $this.Extension.Length)}else{$this.Name};}    
VersionInfo               ScriptProperty System.Object VersionInfo {get=[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($this.FullName);}
```

Now that we know what's available we can use them for our scripts.

Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell
function script:Loop {
    foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem)) {
        ##Some command 
        ##another command
        ## a test
        Write-Output -InputObject ('The current item is named {0}.' -f $file.Name)
        Write-Output -InputObject ('The current items size it {0}.' -f $file.Length)
        Write-Output -InputObject ('The current items hashcode is {0}.



                                                                  ' -f $file.GetHashCode())

    }
}

Loop
```

### Output

```
PS C:\Powershell\Scripts> . "c:\Powershell\Scripts\forloop.ps1"
The current item is named dchero.ps1.
The current items size it 755.
The current items hashcode is 31624384.


The current item is named findinstaller.ps1.
The current items size it 236.
The current items hashcode is 55386574.


The current item is named forloop.ps1.
The current items size it 466.
The current items hashcode is 50677768.
```

Finally you can get fancy and make changes to the objects or test them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell
function script:Loop {
    foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem)) {
        ## command /argument 1

        if ($file.Name -like "*.ps1") {
            <# Action to perform if the condition is true #>
            Write-Output "We've got a Powershell script here!"
            Write-Output "The script is named $file.name"
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "This ain't a Powershell script."
            Write-Output "It's named $file.name"
        }

        ## command / arugment 2
        $newname = $file.BaseName + "-modifiedbyscript" + $file.Extension
        Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName  $newname -WhatIf 
    }
}

Loop
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is probably a bit too unspecific. This Loop function is supposed to use other functions and commands for every file in a folder. The commands used are not always the same. I could also create multiple functions, but that seems a bit ugly to me. An example of the Loop function could be: Loop Write-Output "This file is $File"

Comment: @NandoLawson i've covered a few use cases above with my edits. are you looking for the `-recurse` switch of `get-childitem` ?

Comment: @NandoLawson `function Loop {foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -recurse)) {## command }` adding `recurse` will force `get-childitem` to check and include objects in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a hard guess, if it has nothing to do with what you're looking for let me know and I'll delete this answer. If it has something to do with what you're looking I can understand why it could be "hard to explain".

```bash
function ThisThing {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Expression')]
        [scriptblock] $Expression,

        [parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Condition')]
        [scriptblock] $Condition,

        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0)]
        [object[]] $InputObject
    )

    process {
        if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Expression') {
            if($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
                return & $Expression
            }
            $InputObject | & {
                process {
                    & $Expression
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
                return & { if(& $Condition) { $_ } }
            }
            $InputObject | & {
                process {
                    if(& $Condition) { $_ }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A few examples to test the function:

```bash
ThisThing (0..10) -Expression {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Input = $_
    }
}
```

```bash
Get-ChildItem | ThisThing -Expression {
    if($_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            CreationDate = $_.CreationTime
            Path         = $_.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

```bash
Get-Process | ThisThing -Condition { $_.Name -eq 'svchost' }
```

```bash
ThisThing (Get-Service) -Condition { $_.Status -eq 'Stopped' }
```